# How can I display both values as labels when hovering over chart.js

Tags: chart.js

I have tried to make the labels for both datasets in the chart.js found here.
[example of chart.js](https://codepen.io/rozklad/pen/jaNrWW) to appear when hovering over the different days in the chart

I have tried to add this...

```
   options: {
  tooltips: {
     mode: 'index',
     intersect: false
  },
  hover: {
     mode: 'index',
     intersect: false
  }
```

}

Bu that does not help, in a perfect world I would like to display it like 28 (30) when hovering over SUNDAY. Can somebody help out please?

Answer (score 0):

Since you dont use the build in tooltip to display those values setting tooltip modes dont matter.

To get what you want just put the values in the same span the way you like so you would get this:

```html
<div class="tick">
  SUN
  <span class="value value--this">28 (30)</span>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/leelenaleee/pen/OJjOamw

Comment: Aha, ok I'll go with that then. Thanks